# Does the if sentence on python execute only once?

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame, statements

im new on this, and im using an if statement to load an image in case X thing happens, this is my code:

```
if  self.puntos > 0:
        self.fondo = load_image('Fondo2.png', IMG_DIR)
        self.primera_vez = True
```

So when puntos (points) get over 0 the background changes, the problem is that the new image loads constantly causing low framerates, is this because the if statement executes constantly or what? Thanks

Comment: There is no possible way of knowing that from these 3 lines of code. But this "if" as shown will only execute once.

Comment: This code will only execute once, unless it's inside a loop.

Comment: that if is inside a definition that includes a bunch of other statements that work correctly, but of course they are all separated, no idea why the image loads constantly

Comment: We need to see more code to know what's going on here.

Comment: im going to try to put the code on a separate definition

Comment: It will load the image every time it executes, if `self.puntos` is greater than 0. It doesn't automatically only execute when `self.puntos` changes from less than to more than zero.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should load *all* your images when your program first starts -- that way they're already decompressed and in memory when you need them.

Comment: im working on a simple game with pygame

Comment: I'm assuming this code is in the main loop, so yes, it will be executing every time. Do what @Charles suggests - before the main loop, put `img_fondo2 = load_image('Fondo2.jpg', IMG_DIR)`, then you can change the line in your `if` statement to `self.fondo = img_fondo2`, and it will be much faster.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that's what i think is happening, is there any way to make the image change only once?

Comment: Every statement executes once, unless another part of the program tells it to execute again. e.g. a statement inside a function gets called once, *every time that function is called*, a statement inside a loop gets called *every time that loop is rerun*, and a statement in an if runs *only if the logical expression evaluates to true*.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give more context to this code.

Comment: Also, what do you use `self.primera_vez = True` for?

Comment: @3D1T0R ok thanks for the comment, if i don't put that line the new background appears only where the different character's sprites are, for example i have my character wich i move and as i move it around the screen it starts showing the image where the sprite has been, till every space has been covered by any character

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you want to look to put the same code in a `while` block.

```
while self.puntos > 0:
        self.fondo = load_image('Fondo2.png', IMG_DIR)
        self.primera_vez = True
```

then when `self.puntos` is not > 0 it won't render

Comment: This is *worse* than the original -- the OP was complaining that they were seeing performance that implied that `load_image` was running more than once; now you're *ensuring* that it does so, even if the rest of their program is corrected!